# Can The Data of Application keep although the application is uninstall and install again?

Tags: java, android

May I know is it possible the data of application used still keep although the application used is uninstall and installed back by user? If possible, it need set the code in which part for android studio?

Comment: basically no, but you can place some of your files on the external storage, and they probably won't get removed. Also you can use something like google sign in, and store your data on some server, or firabase, and restore it for the user.

Comment: oh, mean either do user login or store the data in SD card? like this?

Comment: yes, like that.

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can make folder and write files of your choice in External storage, for that you must have to take the "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" permission from user(above Marshmallow, below that mention only in android manifest).

When user install your app again then you can check in the launcher activity or application class, if that folder and files exists.

Answer (score 0):

If your Talking about sqlite and SharedPreferences then No, Once app uninstalled sqlite and SharedPreferences data is cleared even if you clear app data from setting it get cleared.